# Somar uma sequencia de números

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer um algoritmo aqui com esse enunciado:

> Dados um número inteiro n, n>0, e uma sequência com n números inteiros, determinar a soma dos inteiros positivos da sequência. Por exemplo, para a sequência 6 -2  7 0 -5 2  4 o seu programa deve escrever o número 19.

O problema está na hora de somar. Esse é o código que eu fiz:

```
var numero;
var soma;
for (var i = 0; i < 7 ; ) {
   numero=prompt("Entre com o numero: ");
  parseInt(numero);
   while (numero > 0) { 
    soma = soma + numero;
    numero = 0;
 } 
 i++;
}

document.write("A soma dos positivos é: "+soma);
```

O que acontece é que os números não somam e eu não faço ideia de como fazer eles somarem.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que esse `while` vai ficar infinito. Na verdade nem precisas dele pois estás a inserir os numeros um a um e podes somar logo.

Repara também que `parseInt(numero);` só por si não faz nada, tens que atribuir esse valor a uma variável, tipo `numero = parseInt(numero);`.

**Sugestão:**

```js
var numero;
var soma = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  numero = Number(prompt("Entre com o numero: "));
  soma+= numero;
}

document.write("A soma dos positivos é: " + soma);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o código abaixo, mas acredito que terá problemas em explicar o mesmo ao seu instrutor.

```js
var soma = (function* () {
  while (true) {
    var numero = prompt("Entre com o numero: ");
    if (numero != null) 
      yield parseInt(numero);
  }
})()

var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
  total += soma.next().value;
  
alert(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem dois problemas:

1. [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) retorna um inteiro na base especificada
2. A variável soma precisa ser inicializada

```js
var numero;
var soma = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 7 ; ) {
   numero=prompt("Entre com o numero: ");
   numero = parseInt(numero);
   while (numero > 0) { 
    soma = soma + numero;
    numero = 0;
 } 
 i++;
}

document.write("A soma dos positivos é: "+soma);
```

Comment: Valeu, ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Você não inicializou o valor de `soma`, agora da certo ! E não use `while`, use `if`, o while vai ficar dando loop infinito se o numero for <= 0;

```js
var numero;
var soma = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 7 ; ) {
     numero = prompt("Entre com o numero: ");
     if (parseInt(numero) > 0) { 
      soma += parseInt(numero);
      numero = 0;
     } ;
 i++;
};

console.log(soma);
```