# Soma dos pares intervalo digitado

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Estou tentando fazer uma função para somas os números pares em um intervalo. Por exemplo `somaDosPares(6)` `resultado = 12`, porem sempre me retorna o numero do `()`.

```
function somaDosPares(x){
    let soma = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i <= x; i += 2){
        if (i % 2 === 0){
          return soma + x
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Somar uma sequencia de números](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214474/somar-uma-sequencia-de-n%c3%bameros)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já que a variável `i` do laço é incrementada em `+2` começando do `0`, não faz sentido usar um `if` para verificar se o número é par, pois `i` será sempre par. E você está usando o `return` no lugar errado e somando a variável `soma` com `x`, quando deveria somar com `i`:

```js
function somaDosPares(x){
   let soma = 0;
   for(let i = 0; i <= x; i+=2){
     soma += i
   }
   return soma;
}
console.log(somaDosPares(9));
```

Passando `9` à função, por exemplo, irá somar os números pares:

```
0 + 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 = 20
```

Answer (score 6):

Tem alguns problemas no código.

Deve acumular os valores de `i` e não de `x`. Na verdade não estava acumulando, estava apenas somando o valor inicial com o primeiro valor do laço que é 0 também por isso dá sempre 0. Não está executando vários passos, no momento que encontra o `return` o código encerra, dá o resultado e não faz mais nada. Então só pode dar o `return`no final do laço quando já executou tudo.

Outro problema no código que não gera erro mas é ineficiente e sem sentido é o `if` para verificar se o número é par, já é sabido que ele é, você está começando ele no 0 que é par e está somando 2 em cada passo, portanto todos os número de `i` é par.

Então você só precisa da inicialização da vari´ável de acumulação (`soma`), o laço que vai percorrer todos os números desejados, já pulando os ímpares com o `o += 2` que você usou e retornar a variável acumuladora. Note que para ir acumulando usa o operador `+=` que já sabe usar, assim a variável `soma` passa sempre ser o valor dela mais o novo valor a somar, portanto você faz com `soma`  o mesmo que fez com `i`.

```js
function somaDosPares(x) {
    let soma = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= x; i += 2) soma += i
    return soma;
}

console.log(somaDosPares(6));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Sum.js).

Tem como resolver isto de forma performática, mas para resolver o seu algoritmo que pode até ser necessário ser assim para passar em avaliação automática porque é sobre o `for` seria isto aí.

Answer (score 4):

**Solução alternativa:** não precisa nem utilizar um laço de repetição para resolver o problema. Se lembrar da matemática básica deve ter estudado [progressões aritméticas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress%C3%A3o_aritm%C3%A9tica). A sequência 2, 4, 6 é uma PA de três termos iniciando em 2 com razão 2. É facilmente demonstrado que a soma de uma progressão aritmética finita é dada pela soma do primeiro e último termo, multiplicado pela metade da quantidade de termos. Ou seja, a soma de 2, 4 e 6 é dada por (2+6)*3/2, que é 12.

Ao receber o último elemento do intervalo como parâmetro da função, basta verificar se ele é par ou ímpar; se for par ele também será o último termo da PA, se for ímpar o último termo da PA será o número anterior a ele. A quantidade de valores será sempre a metade do último termo da PA.

Portanto:

```js
function somaDosPares(n) {
  const ultimo = (n % 2 == 0) ? n : n-1;
  const primeiro = 2;
  const quantidade = ultimo / 2;
  
  return (primeiro + ultimo) * quantidade / 2;
}

console.log(somaDosPares(6));
console.log(somaDosPares(10));
```

Answer (score 3):

É porque você colocou o retorno antes de terminar o `for`, correção:

```js
function somaDosPares(x){
    let soma = 0;
    for(let i = 2; i <= x; i += 2){                
          soma = soma + i;
    }
    return soma;
}

console.log(somaDosPares(6))
```

e no acumulador é a variável `i` não o `x` e também a estrutura de decisão é desnecessária porque já pode começar do número *par* 2 (*no meu caso exemplo já inicie a variável no 2, já que 0 não influencia na somatória*) e incrementar sempre 2, e isso já acumula os valores pares.